# How to configure irssi to automatically reconnect upon disconnection?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, irssi

I am facing frequent disconnection due to connection issues maybe

```
Irssi: warning SSL read error: server closed connection unexpectedly
```

10:40 -!- Irssi: Connection lost to chat.freenode.net

How to configure irssi to reconnect automatically?